# Can child process send signal to parent after parent dies

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, signals

Suppose that, after sleep, we are sure that parent was died. So, the child process becomes an orphan process. So what will happen, child process send SIGUSR1 to its parent which is init process.

Code :

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if(fork() == 0){
        sleep(10);
        kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After I am running this code, the system logged out. But when I did this in the terminal by

```
sudo kill -10 1
```

nothing happens.
What is the difference between them? And why the system allows me to do this bad thing ?

Comment: Why complicate the question? Ask what will happen if you send `SIGUSR1` to `init`. You can try it without writing any code

Comment: Of course, that'll kill the init process if you have permission. But wouldn't make sense to `wait` in the parent so that you *know* the child isn't orphaned?

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: @Root2A "init" isn't necessarily pid 1. So you might be able to send signal to the subprocess (in systemd init system) which acts as the reaper (whose pid might be different, not 1) for orphans but not necessarily to pid 1.

Comment: @usr So, why the system do not prevent this situtation? Isnt this a bad thing? I do not execute my program with root privilege but it causes crash.

Comment: @Root2A Well, how systemd is designed is a different question :) It can be configured to be run as root in systemd (so that your signals would hit permission issue). But you just generally don't want to sending signals to init system and rewrite your code so that you know which process you're sending your signals to.

Comment: @usr So, you say that, when parent dies, now "init" is the new parent of the child process. But its pid  can different from 1, am i right ? Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211905/discussion-between-root2a-and-usr).

Comment: What do you mean by "the system logged out" Did your computer reboot?

Comment: @mosvy User logs out. Login screen comes again. Not whole computer rebooted.

Comment: Are you sure you sent that signal to init (pid 1), and not to another process (a "subreaper", as already suggested by @usr)? Unless caught or ignored, default action for the `USR1` signal is to terminate. First determine what program exactly did you sent the signal to (print the value of `getppid()`, and look it up via `/proc/<pid>/exe` and `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`).

Comment: @mosvy Yes I did this, print the ppid after the die of parent, it NOT prints the init with pid = 1, it prints another init process with pid !=1. I researched, second init process (pid !=1) , the users init. I think this log out crash happened because I send signal to users(my) init. Am I right ?

Comment: So, which program is it? what would `(sh -c 'sleep .2; realpath /proc/$PPID/exe; tr "\0" " " </proc/$PPID/cmdline'&)` print if run from the same shell as your program?

Comment: @mosvy if you mean which by name, name is init but pid is not 1.